# iOS add a coworker

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

I have an app which is synced via git and on which a second person is working on. What do I have to do to avoid having to change the profile each time e.g. to use the same development profile?

Do I need to register as a "company"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either register as a company, or both register as separate developers.